# Two divs for the same section

Tags: html, css

In the following HTML code, why do they use two divs, one with a class, and the other with an ID, instead of just using one of them for giving the properties?

---

```css
.header {
  background-image: url("https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/web-101/unit-5/htmlcss1-img_canyon.jpeg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
}

#header-text {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 25%;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="header">
    <div  id="header-text">
      <h1>Travel Like Never Before</h1>
      <h2>Whether you're looking for adventure or luxury, let us help you plan your perfect getaway.</h2>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `class` can be reused for other `divs`, `id` is unique can not be used for other elements. its all personal preference. read more https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: What was the actual task?

Comment: "_why do they use two divs?_" Could be 1 of a million different reasons.

Comment: I could post the whole html code, but it is too long. They didn't use the class again anywhere else.

Comment: So, if the class is not used more than once, is it safe to use the div with the id?

Comment: yes it is safe to use id for one time use on one page. outer div has a background and inner div text is positioned on top so that the background is visible. that is why two divs are used.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the `.header` class defines the area for the background image, and the `#header-text` id defines the text that's on top of the image. Since the text is centered and positioned within the larger header area, it needs a separate container so it can be moved around and styled appropriately.